# Implementing horizontal scroll for Yet Another DataTables Column Filter (Yadcf)?

Tags: jquery-plugins, scroll, datatables

Here's the issue in a nutshell, enabling scrollX/scrollY in Jquery Datables hides the column filter plugin: `https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/43`

I placed some of my code here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/LAeVx/6/
```

My main code:

```
$('#displayList').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "asStripClasses": ['even', 'odd ui-state-default'],
                "oLanguage": { "sProcessing": "<div class='processing-div ui-state-focus w120 ui-corner-all'><div style='float:left;'><img src='Styles/images/Spinner.gif'></div><div style='float:left;margin:10px 5px;'>Loading...</div><div class='cleardiv'></div></div>" },
                "oLanguage": { "sZeroRecords": "No dlns available", "sEmptyTable": "No dlns available" },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            }).yadcf([{
                column_number: 0,
                filter_type: "text"
            }, {
                column_number: 1,
                filter_type: "text"
            }, {
                column_number: 2,
                filter_type: "text"
            }, {
                column_number: 3,
                filter_type: "text"
            }, {
                column_number: 4,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
             {
                column_number: 5,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 6,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 7,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 8,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 9,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 10,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 11,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 12,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 13,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 14,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 15,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 16,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 17,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 18,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 19,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 20,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
            {
                column_number: 21,
                filter_type: "text"
            },
             {
                column_number: 22,
                filter_type: "text"
            }]);
```

Has anyone been able to implement horizontal scroll for this plugin? I could not get the solution to work for me.

Comment: the jsfiddle does not seem to work (404) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yadcf DOES support sScrollX/sScrollY (and the scrollX/scrollY) since the 0.8.5.beta.4 version, you can [grab it from here](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/lab/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js)

Comment: Thank you so much...its a perfect filter now!

Answer (score 0):

Just Add in Datatable options

```
     "sScrollX": "100%",
```

I hope that will help you